# What is a 'window' object in JavaScript? And what are its properties?

Tags: javascript, window, bots

I ran into JavaScript code I want to use, and I don't understand some parts of it.

I use the [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) environment to edit it.
The source of the code is the following:
https://github.com/ErmiyaEskandary/Slither.io-bot

For example, in this part of the code:

```
var canvasUtil = window.canvasUtil = (function() {
return {
    // Ratio of screen size divided by canvas size.
    canvasRatio: {
        x: window.mc.width / window.ww,
        y: window.mc.height / window.hh
    },

    // Set direction of snake towards the virtual mouse coordinates
    setMouseCoordinates: function(point) {
        window.xm = point.x;
        window.ym = point.y;
    },
```

I don't understand what the "window" object is, and where it's defined. When I tried to find its definition, I got to a file named DHTML.js, where the only definition for *window* there was:

```
/**
@type {Window}
*/
Window.prototype.window = 0;
```

or

```
/**
@type {Window}
@const
*/
window = 0;
```

(This file is not a part of the repository.)

What is this *window* object? How does it work? And where can I find more information about it?

In the code - what does window.mc, for example, mean? I didn't found any information about the window's property.
There are similar objects in the code like *window*, but this one appears the most.

(I tried to look it up but the information I found in [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) doesn't seems to be related: *[The Window Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)*)

Comment: "I got to a file named DHTML.js"  — I can't see that in the repository for the project you are looking at

Comment: Quentin, you are correct, It does not exist in this repository. I think It's related somehow to the pycharm, but I just don't know. I will add this info to the question

Comment: "I ran into a JS code I want to use and I don't understand some parts of it. I use the pycharm environment to edit it." — PyCharm is an IDE designed for editing Python. It isn't optimised for dealing with JavaScript.

Comment: I need to fuse this script with some python code, that's why pycharm. I added some more specific questions, do you know maybe the answers to them?

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript variable `window` is an `object`, representing a window containing a [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) document; the `document` property points to the DOM document loaded in that window. The `window` object is available in JavaScript of all browsers.

- *[Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window)* (MDN)
- *[JavaScript Window - The Browser Object Model](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp)* (W3Schools)
- *[The Window Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)* (W3Schools)

Comment: "The window object is supported by all browsers" … that support JavaScript.

Comment: "It represents the browser's window" — that barely scrapes the surface of what it represents.

Comment: "w3schools" — are [not as bad as they once were](http://www.w3fools.com/), but are still awful. They are best avoided.

Comment: Wow, three comments and a downvote for just one thing?! And that's just because you don't like `w3s`?! There is an `edit` function for comments too! The information there might not be as good as it could be, but not wrong and easy to understand for _newcommers_. Added `moz dev` too as source and changed the text a bit. @Quentin

Comment: @eisbehr, do you know maybe what window.ws means? or for example, if you will check the repository you will see an object named "window.snake". this is clearly something created specially for this code, yet window is an global object. it is also not clear where this snake object is defined. Do you know to explain it?

Comment: slither.io is a game, your posted repo is just a bot for this. The properties used there are available by this game and just use in the bot. That's the reason why they are _magically_ there. @Yair

Comment: @eisbehr Thanks, do you know where I can find the those properties in the game? I checked the slither.io source but didn't found (maybe I didn't searched in the right place)?
And generally, How I know for each website which properties it's window has?